# Hitting api on server using websocket connection in android

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

I am working on websocket connection to communicate with server.
Now, we have established a connection and able to send and receive message using Autobahn library.

Here is the code:

```
private void start() {

    // wsuri is the url which has to be hit for connecting to the server i.e
    // "ws://hostname:port "
    final String wsuri = "ws://" + mHostname.getText() + ":"
            + mPort.getText();

    // showing status on the UI.
    mStatusline.setText("Status: Connecting to " + wsuri + " ..");

    // enabling disconnect button clicking on which the connection will be
    // disconnected.
    setButtonDisconnect();

    try {
        mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketConnectionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
                // If connection is open, then status will be updated to
                // "connected to..."
                mStatusline.setText("Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
                savePrefs();
                // enabling mSendMessage button and mMessage edit Text.
                mSendMessage.setEnabled(true);
                mMessage.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
                Log.d("ss", payload);
                alert(payload);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                // If connection is lost, alert will be shown connection is
                // lost and status will be set to "Ready".
                alert("Connection lost.");
                mStatusline.setText("Status: Ready.");
                setButtonConnect();
                // disabling mSendMessage button and mMessage edit Text.
                mSendMessage.setEnabled(false);
                mMessage.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    } catch (WebSocketException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

We just have a single method onTextMessage(String payload) to handle response from server.

and to send message to server we use `mConnection.sendTextMessage(mMessage.getText().toString());`

But now we are facing issue that how to hit api on that server?or lets say I want some list of devices or device_Status etc how it will happen??

Any idea how to do that?? At present I am thinking of sending some "key":"pair" value in message in form of json, by which the server will identify what request I have made...

I am still not sure whether this is the right way? Please if somebody can help me in this.

Comment: I will be using json string,,, but here I am asking any other efficient way to get server responses.. similar to how we hit apis and get the required response.

Comment: can you use Autobahn register and call?  With Autobahn, you can 'register' a callback.  Then, your clients can 'call' that callback. Those callbacks could be list_devices(), device_Status(device_id), etc.  If it is an option I can create a better example in an answer.

Comment: yes @Greg I want this only.. please if u can help. :)

Comment: @Greg our server is made using node.js !!

Comment: @Greg why u deleted your answer??

Comment: answer did not appear to address your problem, and my answer was in the wrong language,  so i deleted it :-)  i don't think you are using wamp (autobahn) at least the way I do!